# Should [android-aab] be a synonym for [android-app-bundle]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

The [android-app-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app-bundle) tag is for the new file type for app packaging (`.aab`), which can be used instead of the old `.apk` file type. There's also the [android-aab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-aab) tag which seems to be for the same thing. Seven questions are [tagged with both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app-bundle+android-aab). [android-app-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app-bundle) is the more popular tag, with 33 watchers and 449 questions, while [android-aab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-aab) has just 1 watcher and 55 questions. I don't have the rep yet to suggest synonyms, nor five points in the tag, so I'm posting this meta question. Currently [android-app-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app-bundle) has no synonyms.

[android-app-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app-bundle) description:

> The new app publishing format, the Android App Bundle, is an improved way to package your app.

[android-aab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-aab) description:

> Help us edit this wiki

Should [android-aab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-aab) be a synonym of [android-app-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app-bundle)?